# navbar text elements not vertically aligned (CSS/Bootstrap)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, web

I have been trying to get the text of my navbar elements to centrally vertically aligned but just can't seem to do it.

Here is the bootstrap I have been using:
http://pastebin.com/PKd2iJeJ

Below is my current CSS style file:

```
body {
background-color: #FFF;
}

#pageHeaderTop {
background-color: #FFFFFF;
width:100%;
border-bottom-style: solid;
border-width: 1px;
border-color: #D1D1D1;
height: auto;
}

#pageHeaderBottom {
background-color: #D1D1D1;
width:100%;
border-top-style: solid;
border-width: 1px;
border-color: #FFFFFF;
}

.logoHeader {
width: 1200px;
text-align: left;
padding: 20px;
}

.nav {
width: 1200px;
}

.nav a {
color: #5A5A5A;
font-size: 11px;
font-weight: bold;
/* 10px top & bottom 14px left and right*/
padding: 10px 14px;
text-transform: uppercase;
}

.nav li {
display: inline;
}

#pageContent {
border:#999 1px solid;
border-top: none;
background-color:#F4F4F4;
width:1200px;
}

.contentArea {
text-align: left;
margin-left: 24px;
}

#pageFooter {
border:#999 1px solid;
border-top: none;
background-color:#F4F4F4;
width:1200px;
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. I'm fairly new to web development so if you could expain in layman terms that would be great!

Comment: could you please share a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) with us..

Comment: Apologies, haven't used fiddle before, I have done it but can't seem to add my bootstrap CSS code in: http://jsfiddle.net/gvv7pmxa/

Comment: thanks for the fiddle...could you please explain a bit more clearly, how the menu is to be aligned?

Comment: If you look at this screenshot: http://snag.gy/O9C1k.jpg

Each of the tabs 'home', 'xbox', 'playstation' and 'contact us' appear to be slightly above the vertical middle of the navbar if that makes sense? I am trying to get them perfectly in the vertical middle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few issues. Bootstrap adds 10px bottom margin to `ul`. You can remove that bottom margin and use `line-height` to vertically align `li` inside `ul`
See this code snippet:

```css
body {
 background-color: #FFF;
}

#pageHeaderTop {
 background-color: #FFFFFF;
 width:100%;
 border-bottom-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
 border-color: #D1D1D1;
 height: auto;
}

#pageHeaderBottom {
 background-color: #D1D1D1;
 width:100%;
 border-top-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
 border-color: #FFFFFF;
}

.logoHeader {
 width: 1200px;
 text-align: left;
 padding: 20px;
}

.nav {
 width: 1200px;
    height: 30px;
}

.nav a {
 color: #5A5A5A;
    font-size: 11px;
    font-weight: bold;
 /* 10px top & bottom 14px left and right*/
    padding: 10px 14px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.nav-ul {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.nav li {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
}

#pageContent {
 border:#999 1px solid;
 border-top: none;
 background-color:#F4F4F4;
 width:1200px;
}

.contentArea {
 text-align: left;
 margin-left: 24px;
}

#pageFooter {
 border:#999 1px solid;
 border-top: none;
 background-color:#F4F4F4;
 width:1200px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
   <title>Rapid Codes - Get It Now!</title>
    <link href="style/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="style/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
  
<body>

<div align="center" id="mainWrapper">
    <div id="pageHeaderTop">
 <div class="logoHeader">
     <img src="http://www.rapidcodes.co.uk/style/NewLogo.png" width="400" height="50" alt="Logo"/>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="pageHeaderBottom">
    <div class="nav">
        <ul class="pull-left nav-ul">
          <li><a href="http://rapidcodes.co.uk">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="xbox.php">Xbox</a></li>
            <li><a href="playstation.php">PlayStation</a></li>
         </ul>
         <ul class="pull-right">
            <li><a href="contact_us.php">Contact Us</a></li>
         </ul>
     </div>
</div>
    
  <div id="pageContent">
  <div class="contentArea">Test</div></div>

    <div id="pageFooter">© 2015 Rapid Codes</div>
    
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you. I used this code and it didn't quite work how I wanted to, but I've played around with it a little bit and now I've got it where I wanted. Thanks again!

Comment: @Jurfer that's how you learn, by tweaking it a bit here and there. Glad to help you :)